# Update the android default database table schema

Tags: database, android

May we have rights to update the android database table schema such like People, Organization,Calendar,Events. i want to add triggers on the update, delete and insert of the above mention tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cant. Those are content providers and the behind data storage is not always SQLite, that can be XML, Web Service or something else.

Comment: Well, you could by modifying the firmware, but I suspect that is beyond the scope of what the questioner is seeking...